# Concurrency point is centroid through barycentric coordinates

Tags: geometry, vectors, barycentric-coordinates

Consider a point $X$ inside $\triangle ABC$, and construct $AD, BE, CF$ passing through $X$ and ending on the opposite sides. Let these be vectors. Prove that if $\vec{AD}+\vec{BE}+\vec{CF}$ is equal to $0$ then $X$ is the centroid.

Because this involves vectors, I am thinking a potential approach would use barycentric coordinates, and to take advantage of the properties of $D,E,F$ determined by the center. How would I prove this?

Edit : So I have barycentrics for the vectors $AD, BE, CF$ as coordinates where $a+b=1, c+d=1, e+f=1$ and $(1,-a,-b), (-c,1,-d), (-e,-f,1)$. How do I relate themselves to a common center?

Comment: Express all the vectors in question as combinations of $A,B$ and $C$. Ask what it means to be the centroid in relation to the position of $D,E$ and $F$ then show that only happens when the vectors in question sum to $0$. I recommend sketching a few triangles and seeing what happens.

Comment: If i define the center in bary as (x,y,z), how will I get the points D,E,F on the sides? I know that I can then get vectors AD,BE,CF by subtracting D from A, etc... and then add them together. How do I get the points D,E,F on the sides?

Comment: So if $A$ and $B$ are position vectors points on the side will be of the form $A(1-t)+tB$ for some $t \in [0,1]$. Alternatively think of it as $A + t(B-A)$ so that it's the vector starting at $A$ and then traveling along the vector $B-A$ which is the side between $A$ and $B$ (why?). The midpoint will be when $t=\frac12$.

Comment: Yes, I know that. So I have barycentrics for the vectors AD, BE, CF as corodinates where a+b=1, c+d=1, e+f=1 and (1,-a,-b), (-c,1,-d), (-e,-f,1) How do I relate themselves to a common cneter?

Comment: How do I relate these points to a common center and solve?

Comment: I suggest you read up about "barycentric coordinates" basics first, which will take very short time. These are the correct coordinates : $A=(1,0,0), B=(0,1,0), C=(0,0,1)$, $D=(0,t,1-t), E=(1-u,0,u), F=(v,1-v,0)$. For concurrency, read Ceva's theorem applied using barycentrics.

Comment: Ok, so I have that (1-t)/t*(1-u)/u*(1-v)/v = 1 if concurrence is to occur. This means that (1-t)(1-u)(1-v)=tuv. But many points have that property. To get the vectors AD, BE, CF, I had e.g. A+AD=D so AD=D-A=(-1,t,1-t) but the coords aren't normalised here?

Comment: @oiuio I have posted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let the coordinates be $A=(1,0,0), B=(0,1,0), C=(0,0,1)$, $D=(0,t,1-t), E=(1-u,0,u), F=(v,1-v,0)$.

Writing $\vec{AD}=\vec{D}-\vec{A}$ etc, the condition $\vec{AD}+\vec{BE}+\vec{CF}=0$ gives
$$\vec{D}+\vec{E}+\vec{F}=\vec{A}+\vec{B}+\vec{C}$$
In terms of the barycentric coordinates,
$$(1-u+v, t+1-v, 1-t+u)=(1,1,1)$$
Equating the corresponding coordinates yields $t=u=v$.
Finally for concurrence to hold, by Ceva's theorem,
$tuv = (1-t)(1-u)(1-v)$. Setting $u=v=t$ we have $t^3=(1-t)^3\Rightarrow t=1-t \Rightarrow t=1/2$.

Thus $D,E,F$ are midpoints of the sides and the concurrence point $X$ is indeed the centroid of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Could you rewrite it as a+b+c-d-e-f=(0,0,0)? or (v-u,t-v,u-t)=(0,0,0)? But I am confused because can't (0,0,0) be equally replaced with (1,1,1) and still represent the same point?

Comment: @oiuio A) Yes we can certainly write $A+B+C-D-E-F=\vec{0}$ as $(v-u,t-v,u-t)=(0,0,0)$ because $\vec{0}$ has coordinates $(0,0,0)$. I wrote it in this manner because I could also divide both sides by $3$ and from $\frac{A+B+C}{3}=\frac{D+E+F}{3}$, tell that both triangles have same centroid. B) No, $(0,0,0)$ cannot be replaced by $(1,1,1)$; why do you think so? Barycentric coordinates are unique.